# Mobile Angular UI Modals

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the Mobile Angular UI to create a modal, and whenever I try to implement it as it's shown on the documentation it just shows the overlay (modal) on top of everything, and the close buttons don't function. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, I'm new to angular.

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- Application body -->
    <div class="app">
        <div class="navbar-absolute-top"></div>
        <div class="navbar-absolute-bottom"></div>
        <div class="app-body" style="padding-top:10vh; padding-bottom:10vh">
            <ng-view>
                <div id="geolocation" style="height:80vh; width:100%"></div>
            </ng-view>
        </div>
        <!-- Overlays -->
        <div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Overlay content -->
    <div ui-content-for="modals">
      <div class="modal modal-overlay" ui-if='modal2' ui-state='modal2'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button class="close"
                      ui-turn-off="modal2">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button ui-turn-off="modal2" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
              <button ui-turn-off="modal2" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Initialize App -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried to see console outputs? it is always useful. @wolfz

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in rails, issue for me was with modal being presented inside of the app-body `<div class='app-body'></div>` instead  of `<div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>`. So if you are using rails just yield in between modals.

```
<div ui-yield-to="modals"><%= yield :modals %></div>
```

And your modal need to wrap into:

```
<% content_for :modals do %>
<div ui-content-for="modals"> 
...
</div>
<% end %>
```